# Я никак не смогу сделать смарт часы на Django. Выводит время - легко, а вот чтобы часы обнавлялись не получается. Помогите! Без JS

Tags: python, django, datetime

```
import time


# Create your views here.

def index(request):


    clock = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S %p')


    context = {'clock':clock}

    return ....
```

Comment: Если возникнут вопросы - пишите их под ответом, чтобы мне пришли уведомления. Если все ок и ответ помог вам, то можете поставить галочку слева от ответа. См. справку [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

В общем виде я категорически не рекомендую это делать без JS.
В production среде не место подобным решениям ибо они создают лишнюю нагрузку, увеличивают траффик и мешают пользователю.
В любой команде за такое оторвут руки.

#### Обновление страницы с помощью HTML тега

Но если это часть какого-то хитроумного теста или челенджа
*(а-ля вывода `hello world` без использования функции main и пр.)* 
**то в том(и только в том случае)** можно попробовать обновлять страницу используя HTML-тег `<meta>`

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="seconds;URL">
```

В атрибуте `content` через точку с запятой вы указываете количество секунд, через которое должно выполниться перенаправление и URL - куда Вас следует перенаправить.

Обычно он используется для перенаправления страниц, у которых изменился адрес(другими словами для редиректов), но если указать в нем интервал в секунду и ссылку на самого себя, то он будет обновлять страницу каждую секунду, что может быть решением Вашей задачи.

Вам стоит поместить данный тег в `<head></head>` указав количество секунд и адрес страницы

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;http://localhost:3000/smart_watch/">
```

#### На всякий случай

На случай, если мои убеждения дошли до цели оставлю здесь это:

##### Обновление страницы на JavaScript

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.reload();
    },1000);
</script>
```

##### Часы обновляемые целиком и полностью на клиентской части.

```js
let watch = document.getElementById('watch');

watch.innerText = (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString();

setInterval(function() {
   watch.innerText = (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString();
},1000);
```

```css
#watch{
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#333333;
    color:#00FF00;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div id='watch'></div>
```

---

**Еще раз повторюсь:**
В общем виде такие задачи без JS решать нецелесообразно(а в большинстве невозможно), поэтому некоторые пользователи совершенно оправданно сочли данную задачу нонсенсом и вздором и начали ставить минусы и голосовать за закрытие данного вопроса.

Если Вы хотите заниматься веб-разработкой и быть fullstack-разработчиком, но при этом совсем не хотите работать с JavaScript, то Вам стоит пересмотреть, а тем ли Вы занимаетесь.

А если Вы хотите быть исключительно backend-разработчиком, то не стоит смотреть и пытаться выполнять задачи, которые требуют интерактивности на стороне клиента.

---

#### Альтернативы JavaScript

Если вообще прям JavaScript не любите, то можете попробовать писать клиентский код на:

- Dart
- Kotlin
- Elm
- CoffeeScript
- TypeScript
- ClojureScript
- пр.

С последующей компиляцией всего этого добра в JavaScript.
То есть писать Вы будете на другом языке, но браузер все равно в итоге будет выполнять JS.

На данный момент JavaScript это **единственный язык** поддерживаемый всеми современными популярными браузерами.